# Laravel Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

Having three tables, booking, category, pivot_booking.

**In Booking model -**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\Modules\Backend\Entities\Category::class, "pivot_booking","booking_id","category_id")->withPivot('count');
}
```

**In Category model-**

```
public function bookings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\Modules\Frontend\Entities\Booking::class, "pivot_booking","booking_id","category_id")->withPivot('count');
}
```

In my controller, I want to fetch data from both tables as

```
$booking = \Modules\Frontend\Entities\Booking::with('category')->where('id',$decrypted)->first();
```

**But getting the following error:**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'pivot_booking' (SQL: select `pivot_booking`.*, `pivot_booking`.`booking_id` as `pivot_booking_id`, `pivot_booking`.`category_id` as `pivot_category_id`, `pivot_booking`.`count` as `pivot_count` from `pivot_booking` inner join `pivot_booking` on `pivot_booking`.`id` = `pivot_booking`.`category_id` where `pivot_booking`.`booking_id` = 1255)

Need quick help.

Comment: I am strongly against not following standard naming standards for Laravel, I'm 90% sure you issue is because you pivot table is named pivot_booking instead of booking_category. Checkout your solution here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/pivot-table-naming-for-composed-words

Comment: I know you are right but I am helpless as I am working on a project which was developed by some other developers. Since renaming the table is not possible, as this may affect other pages. You can point out any solution, if possible.

Comment: Is `pivot_booking` a **pivot** table?